# Smooth Transition between Activities like in the Google IO 2014 App

Tags: android, android-activity, transition

How would I implement smooth Transitions between Activities such as they are implemented in the [Google IO 2014](https://github.com/google/iosched/) App?

It seems as if they are just replacing Fragments but from the Code it seems as if they are just regularly starting an Activity? The Source Code for the Switching (Navigation Drawer) can be found here: [BaseActivity.java](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/BaseActivity.java)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just found out how they manage to accomplish this in their App:

They call

```
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

in the onCreate Methode of the Activities that inherit from the BaseActivity. (You could also call it in the BaseActivity, though)