# How to get smooth transition when changing activities

Tags: java, android

I am still kinda new in android development and I can not figure out how can I get smooth transition when switching between activities. I currently have [this](https://vimeo.com/214888386)

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251104/smooth-transition-between-activities-like-in-the-google-io-2014-app

Comment: @volodos I have already tried it before, but that does not work for me.

Comment: Activities flash on back navigation after process death or the system killing the previous view hierarchy. It's what Activities do.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: In your case, this flash could also be the result of some odd intent flag you added to the intent, for example CLEAR_TASK or NEW_TASK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing worked for me. I had to change type of animation to get rid of weird flash.

Answer (score 1):

You can try these two option.

In the intent you use to switch to another activity add this flag

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION
```

and in the style asset of this activity (found trough the manifest)
add this line

```
   <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
```